# Bootstrap grid layout not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and I have two columns :`.col-md-9` and `.col-md-3`.

However, the one with the class `.col-md-3` is somehow taking full width of the parent row, instead of just taking 25%.

Why is this happening?

**Note: Run the snippet in full page and resize the browser window until you can see this behaviour.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">12</span>
          Matt Damon
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">9</span>
          Brad Pitt
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">4</span>
          George Clooney
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">2</span>
          Angelina Jolie
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that as you shrink your browser window you hit the Bootstrap breakpoints in descending size order. LG, MD, SM, and XS.

The `col-md-*` classes only affect elements at breakpoints MD and larger; MD and LG.

The `hidden-xs` class, however, only affects the XS breakpoint.

When you hit the SM breakpoint, neither of these classes is affecting the `div` in question and so it reverts to its default styling, full-width.

You can use the `hidden-sm` class in addition and it will hide it at that breakpoint too.

Here is a handy chart that shows which breakpoints `hidden` and `visible` classes affect elements: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `hidden-sm` too

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">12</span>
          Matt Damon
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">9</span>
          Brad Pitt
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">4</span>
          George Clooney
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">2</span>
          Angelina Jolie
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `col-sm-*`.

Bootstrap has 4 media queries:

- `col-xs`
- `col-sm`
- `col-md`
- and `col-lg`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">12</span>
          Matt Damon
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">9</span>
          Brad Pitt
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">4</span>
          George Clooney
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">2</span>
          Angelina Jolie
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's no col-xs-0 by default

Comment: Why the downvote? This shows it at 25% width, like you wanted.

Comment: Probably because Bootstrap doesn't have a `col-xs-0` class. Also, using both `col-sm-*` and `col-md-*` is redundant if they are both using the same number of columns, the same effect would be achieved simply by using only `col-sm-*`